# CKEditor not reload in flex

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, ckeditor

I have used [this CKEditor](http://blog.aboutme.be/2009/10/25/ckeditor-running-in-flex-and-air/) in flex.

```
<ckeditor:CKEditor id="editor1" width="100%" height="100%">
        <ckeditor:htmlText>
            <![CDATA[

            ]]>
        </ckeditor:htmlText>
</ckeditor:CKEditor>
```

This editor is in one screen. Which reload every when i come back to that screen.

When i load first time then CKEditor  working fine. I can add text to that editor like:

```
editor1.htmlText = "<some html text>"
```

Ans also i can clear the text using.

```
editor1.htmlText = "";
```

**Problem:**
But, when i go to another screen and come back to editor screen again then it behave weird. I can not add html text and also can not clear.

on first load it looks in inspecting element like:

```
<div id="ck0" style="position: absolute; background-color: transparent;
border: 0px none; visibility: hidden; left: 312px; top: 114px;">
```

[image]

While when i reload that screen then.

```
<div id="ck0" style="position: absolute; background-color: transparent;
 border: 0px none; visibility: hidden; left: 312px; top: 114px;">
<div id="ck1" style="position: absolute; background-color: transparent;
 border: 0px none; visibility: visible; left: 312px; top: 114px;">
```

[image]

There are displayed two editor previous is not removed and new load with `ck1` id.

It will always add new editor with increment in id like ck1, ck2 and so on., even if i remove it.

Don't know why this happens. I tried all the things but didn't succeeded. 
Any help would greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** In body it will added following code:

```
<body onpageshow="event.persisted && (function(){var allInstances = CKEDITOR.instances, editor, doc;for ( var i in allInstances ){ editor = allInstances[ i ]; doc = editor.document; if ( doc ) { doc.$.designMode = "off"; doc.$.designMode = "on"; }}})();">
```

Comment: I think that you've something wrong in your code (Flex / JS). Try to verify that, or you can add your code to verify that with you ...

Comment: @akmozo i have already added my code here for ckeditor

Comment: @akmozo I have used `<s:Module` for different section when click on section1 load that then section2 and so on. I have notes editor in section1 when click on section2 and then again come back to section 1 then CKeditor added new ck1 as explain in question.